C++ extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of variable 'val'
I'm trying meta-programming so that factorial can be computed in compile-time. Here is the 1st version:
template <int N>
struct Fac {
    static const int val = N * Fac<N - 1>::val;
};

template <>
struct Fac<1> {
    static const int val = 1;
};

Very clear. And then I was thinking about not using const, which leads to the outside definition of the member variable. However, the first question came out:
template <int N>
struct Fac {
    static int val;
};

template <>
struct Fac<1> {
    static int val;
};

template <int N>
int Fac<N>::val = N * Fac<N - 1>::val;

template <>         // <- error: extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of variable 'val'
int Fac<1>::val = 1;

The wrong is "extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of variable 'val'".
Then I found without template <> it worked:
template <int N>
struct Fac {
    static int val;
};

template <>
struct Fac<1> {
    static int val;
};

template <int N>
int Fac<N>::val = N * Fac<N - 1>::val;

int Fac<1>::val = 1;

At first, I thought template <> struct Fac<1> was redundant so I removed it, but I found then template <> had to be added in front of Fac<1>::val as below:
template <int N>
struct Fac {
    static int val;
};

template <int N>
int Fac<N>::val = N * Fac<N - 1>::val;

template <>
int Fac<1>::val = 1;

Well, I can understand it as a full specification of the template class.
However, when adding another template parameter to prove my opinion, it went wrong again:
template <int N, int M>
struct Fac {
    static int val;
};

template <int N, int M>
int Fac<N, M>::val = N * Fac<N - 1, M>::val;

template <int M>    // <- error: nested name specifier 'Fac<1, M>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
int Fac<1, M>::val = 1;

The error was "nested name specifier 'Fac<1, M>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization".
The correction is to add the definition of the partial specification version of Fac<1, M> as below:
template <int N, int M>
struct Fac {
    static int val;
};

template <int M>
struct Fac<1, M> {
    static int val;
};

template <int N, int M>
int Fac<N, M>::val = N * Fac<N - 1, M>::val;

template <int M>
int Fac<1, M>::val = 1;

I am asking for a favour to explain all these phenomena.
My environment:
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

please include the compiler errors when asking about compiler errors. They usually hold good information

@463035818_is_not_an_ai well, I added it in the context, but I'll highlight it.

[OT]: specialization should be done for 0, not 1.

@Jarod42 It's the same. And also here we intend to discuss template parameter specification instead of the algorithm.

This looks more like trial and error to me. I would instead recommend a good c++ book because c++ is one of the most difficult language to learn.

"    am asking for a favour to explain all these phenomena"     I would recommend asking one question per post instead of every possible combination. People might know answer to one snippet but not other.

I agree with @Alex that this looks more like trying to learn c++ from trial and error which is not a good idea. It take years to learn c++ properly and that too when learned from a good c++ book.

@Alex Hi. Tbh, it's just one question which can only be clarified with multiple examples.

First, we need to figure out there are three kinds of template declaration:

non-specialised template declaration
partially specialised template declaration
fully specialised template declaration

If we define members of a class in an out-of-class way with full specification, there are two methods.

If there is only a non-specialised template declaration (also, primary declaration), then the full specification can only come from it. In such a case, template <> is needed to clarify this definition derives from the primary declaration.

template <int N, typename T>
struct Fac {
    static const int val;
};

template <int N, typename T>
const int Fac<N, T>::val = N * Fac<N - 1, T>::val;


// fully specialised from the primary declaration
template <>
const int Fac<1, double>::val = 1;


If a fully specialised declaration existed, the full specification can only derived from it instead of the primary declaration. In order to avoid ambiguance, template <> is emitted.

template <int N, typename T>
struct Fac {
    static const int val;
};

template <int N, typename T>
const int Fac<N, T>::val = N * Fac<N - 1, T>::val;

// fully specialised template declaration
template <>
struct Fac<1, double> {
    static const int val;
};

// fully specialised from fully specialised declaration, no template <>
const int Fac<1, double>::val = 1;

The type template parameter is useless, and is only used for demonstration.

You have two problems:

missing const making val inconsistent when instantiate val (note it is a good practice to make this const, so this values could be used in some context at compile time - like static_assert).
also template<> is not needed when instantiating value for fixed value 1

template <int N>
struct Fac {
    static const int val;
};

template <>
struct Fac<1> {
    static const int val;
};

const int Fac<1>::val = 1;

template <int N>
const int Fac<N>::val = N * Fac<N - 1>::val;

https://godbolt.org/z/abMYfajTb
Note also that since C++11 you can use constexpr making this much more simple.
constexpr int fact(int x)
{
    return x == 0 ? 1 : x * fact(x - 1);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/477dWqMTv

I was wrong it is not a must just a good practice, so this value could be used at compile time: https://godbolt.org/z/sGPqE1bhW - I've fixed answer.

"Static member variables also would be evaluated in compile-time". No, only constexpr (and const might be equivalent to constexpr in some cases as this one)would be evaluated at compile time (but with as-if rule, optimizer might do the job). static would be done before main (unless delayed init).

@Jarod42 You're correct. I mix normal static variables and static member variables. The purpose of static here is that I can use the member variable without constructing an object. Thank you.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah, I've deleted it.
